# Is there better third-party scanner software for OS X than Preview?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, pdf, scanning

I'm not overly happy with the UI for interfacing with the scanner on my Epson WF-3250 series scanner that's provided by the latest Preview that comes with OS X 10.10. It's clunky and awkward, crashes often. You have to reselect your options every time you use.

It's just, honestly, not very Apple-like.

**Is there reliable third party scanning software that I could use in place of Preview for obtaining PDF scans of multi-page documents on the Epson's auto-feeder?**

Edit: With OS X 10.9, Epson stopped shipping its own scanner utility. The ship a driver and instructions to use Preview for acquiring images on OS X.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may also want to look into the excellent [VueScan](http://www.hamrick.com/). I haven't had a need for it in several years but back in the day it was really one of the best there is. Looks like it is still updated regularly.

Answer (score 6):

[PDFScanner](https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/pdfscanner-simple-document/id410968114?l=en&mt=12) from the app store is awesome. Very fast. Simple. Achieves small file sizes.

Comment: I confirm. Mac OS Preview created a 910 kB file, PDFScanner 59 kB, quality of the scanned black and white document is even better.

Answer (score 3):

You might try [Paperless](https://marinersoftware.com/products/paperless/).  It retains the options across scans, and can do multi-page etc.

(And, relevant to the ADF):

- Paperless will display the Image Capture dialog.
- If the ADF is supported by Image Capture, the dialog will display Feeder as an
  option to acquire with.
- Choosing Scan will cause all pages in the ADF to be scanned.
- All scan jobs (multipage documents) scanned before
  choosing Done will be imported into Paperless as separate multipage
  documents.

[Source](https://marinersoftware.deskpro.com/kb/articles/310-what-are-the-differences-between-scan-and-scan-multi-in-paperless-2)